# Android Room, can only get 1 result from query but checked and there should be more

Tags: android, android-room

I checked the database, there should be 4 results with the same group. I checked the insertion everything works fine.

```
@Dao
public interface MemberDao {
  @Query("Select * from `Member` where id=:groupsId")
  List<Member> getMembers(int groupsId);
}
```

Here is my method to retrieve data,

```
public List<Member> getMembers(final Group group){
    LoadData d = new LoadData();
    d.onComplete = this;
    d.execute(group);

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onOutput(List<Member> result) {
    member = result;
    for(Member m : member){
        System.out.println(m.name);
    }
}

public class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Group, Void, List<Member>> {
    private OnTaskComplete onComplete =null;

    @Override
    protected List<Member> doInBackground(Group... groups) {
        List<Member> result = memberDao.getMembers(groups[0].id);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Member> result){
        onComplete.onOutput(result);

    }
}
```

But the result only has 1 in it and there should be 4 member in the List.

so My question is:

1. if I can get 1 result back, the groupsId is not a problem. 
   So why does it only return 1 result?
2. I try to just return the whole list of member regardless of the groupsId, and I can get exactly 4 back. So it only happens when I try to specify a groups Id.

Does someone know why it behaves like that ?

P.S. Here is the Member class.

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(parentColumns  =
    "id", childColumns = "groupsId", entity = Group.class))
public class Member {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public long groupsId;

public Member(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setGroupsId(long groupsId){
    this.groupsId = groupsId;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}
```

[image]
I posted it here to show the verified data.

Comment: I verified. The data is correct.

Comment: sorry, I dont understand. Does it mean to dump the result to a cursor instead of List<Member>?

Comment: yes, see `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor`

Comment: D/database: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@5f25918
            0 {
               id=1
               name=user1
               groupsId=1
            }
            1 {
               id=2
               name=user2
               groupsId=1
            }
            <<<<<    Here is the cursor result I reset the database and added 2 members in group, when I switch to use a GroupId with the query. it gives me this.

Comment: D/database: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@e443078
            0 {
               id=1
               name=user1
               groupsId=1
            }
            <<<<<

Comment: OK then post your sqlite3 session, how you verified your data? did you type: select * from Member where id = 1 ???

Comment: I edit my post to show the image of verified data and I am using sqlite browser

Comment: Thanks for trying. I some how rewrite the groupId to use Long dataType throughout the whole application and it returns all the members. But it is still unknown why it would return 1 instead of 4 results.

Comment: so now compare `@Query("Select * from `Member` where id=:groupsId")` with your `sqlite3` query: `select * from Memeber where groupId = 1;`

Comment: so, did you notice: Select * from Member where **id** =:groupsId?

Comment: you are right. I messed up the query. It should be groupsId =: groupsId instead of id =: groupsId. thats why it only return 1 result. Found the Answer

Answer (score 1):

add room annotations:

```
public class Member {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private Long userId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "group_id")
    private Long groupId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "username")
    public String name;

    ...
}
```